# Android How to get real measure of a side of an ImageView to make it square?

Tags: android, imageview, measure

I'd like to know how to get to get real measure of a side of an ImageView to make it square.

For example:

I have this ImageView

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="50"
 android:background="@drawable/image"/>
```

What I want to do is simply to get real Height measure (in DP or PX) to make a square using this code:

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView1.getLayoutParams().width = imageView1.getHeight();
```

But if I use one of these codes I get always "0":

```
   imageView1.getHeight();
   imageView1.getLayoutParams().height;
   imageView1.getMeasuredHeight();
```

because the I set layout_height "0dp" to have a 50% layout_weight.

There is a way to make ImageView square??

Many thaks...

Comment: What result do you want? Square `ImageView` in half of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
imageView.measure(imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), imageView.getMeasuredHeight());
imageView.getHeight();
imageView.getWidth();
```

Comment: After `measure` method `getHeight()` still returns 0. Only `getMeasuredHeight()` changes.

Comment: I tried by using imageView.getMeasuredHeight() after first line and in this way I get a measure different from 0 but when I apply it by using imageView1.getLayoutParams().width = imageView1.getMeasuredHeight();  imageView is really small. Maybe I have to convert the measure in other unit?

Comment: remove all lines and just use this one line `imageView1.getLayoutParams().width = imageView1.getLayoutParams.height();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public class Something extends Activity {
   ImageView imageView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_something);
      imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImage);
      getDimensions();
  }

    private void getDimensions() {
      imageView.measure(imageView.getMeasuredWidth(),
      imageView.getMeasuredHeight());
      int Width = getMeasuredWidth();
      int Height = getMeasuredHeight();
      Toast.makeText(this, "width: " + Width + " height: " + Height,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

}
```

It works for me, using api 4 / 17, target api 10.
Result is in px.